# AttributeError: 'XGBRegressor' object has no attribute 'feature_names_in_'

Tags: python, xgboost

I'm building a model with XGBRegressor.
After fitting the model, I want to visualise the feature importance.

```
reg = xgb.XGBRegressor(base_score=0.5, booster='gbtree', n_estimators=1000)
reg.fit(X_train, y_train, eval_set=[(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test)], verbose=100)


fi = pd.DataFrame(data=reg.feature_importances_, index=reg.feature_names_in_, columns=['importance'])
fi.sort_values('importance').plot(kind='barh', title='Feature Importance')
plt.show()
```

I received the error `AttributeError: 'XGBRegressor' object has no attribute 'feature_names_in_'`. I've already upgraded sklearn and restarted the jupyter notebook but still receiving this error. All my feature names are string.

I have no issue of getting `feature_importances_` .

Answer (score 3):

`reg.get_booster().feature_names`
try this instead